# Why is the bracha for Temple considered thanksgiving and not a request?

Tags: shemoneh-esrei

The Shemoneh Esrei is organized with three brachot denoting praise, the middle brachot consisting of requests, and the last three consisting of thanksgiving. Why is asking for the Temple considered thanksgiving and not a request? Shouldn't the thanksgiving section really begin with the bracha for thanksgiving, starting with Modiim?

Comment: Actually, there are words of request in "Retzei", as there are in "Sim Shalom".